# predict values using xgboost algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, prediction, xgboost

I have written code for boston house pricing using Xgboost
Here is the code

```
import treelite
import xgboost
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import treelite.runtime     # runtime module

X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)
print('dimensions of X = {}'.format(X.shape))
print('dimensions of y = {}'.format(y.shape))

dtrain = xgboost.DMatrix(X, label=y)
params = {'max_depth':3, 'eta':1, 'silent':1, 'objective':'reg:linear',
          'eval_metric':'rmse'}
bst = xgboost.train(params, dtrain, 20, [(dtrain, 'train')])

bst.save_model('bst1.model')

bst = xgboost.Booster({'nthread':4}) #init model
bst.load_model("bst1.model") # load data

#Now I want to make prediction using above model

(Pdb) bst.predict(X,10,20)
*** AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'feature_names'
(Pdb) bst.predict(10,20)
*** AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'feature_names'
(Pdb)
```

What is the correct way to make a prediction for input values 10 and 20?

Edit

After taking Adji advice

```
(Pdb) bst.predict([[10,20]])
*** AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'feature_names'
(Pdb) bst.predict([10,20])
*** AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'feature_names'
```

Comment: From the error messages, you see the input to `bst.predict` must have an attribute called `feature_names`. i.e. - it can't be an int, an array, a list or any other basic type. from the example in the 'get started' page, you see you need an `xgb.DMatrix` object as input.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to change

`10,20` to a matrix, or

`[[10,20]]` (follow the format of `xgb.Dmatrix(...)` result)

Comment: [link](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get_started.html) check this link, maybe it's help you. Test value have same format with train value, idk the result of ```print(dtrain)```

Comment: or check this [link](https://www.kaggle.com/mathvv/prediction-on-house-prices-xgboost-tutorial/notebook) maybe you'll find something @user2129623 . I think that ```bst.predict(...)``` need ```xgb.DMatrix(...)``` as an input that has 'feature_names' on it.